# Error MSB4018 The "Nerdbank.GitVersioning.Tasks.GetBuildVersion" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I am getting this errors in VS2019.

I verified packages are installed, but its not resolved.

Is anyone give a solution to resolve this issue?

```
Error   MSB4018 The "Nerdbank.GitVersioning.Tasks.GetBuildVersion" task failed unexpectedly.

System.ArgumentNullException: Base directory must not be null to be able to deserialize filter paths. Ensure that one was passed to GetJsonSettings, and that the version.json file is being written to a Git repository.
Parameter name: repoRelativeBaseDirectory
   at Nerdbank.GitVersioning.FilterPathJsonConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Nerdbank.GitVersioning.VersionFile.TryReadVersionJsonContent(String jsonContent, String repoRelativeBaseDirectory)
   at Nerdbank.GitVersioning.VersionFile.GetVersion(String projectDirectory, String& actualDirectory)
   at Nerdbank.GitVersioning.VersionFile.GetVersion(String projectDirectory)
   at Nerdbank.GitVersioning.VersionOracle..ctor(String projectDirectory, Repository repo, Commit head, ICloudBuild cloudBuild, Nullable`1 overrideVersionHeightOffset, String projectPathRelativeToGitRepoRoot)
   at Nerdbank.GitVersioning.VersionOracle.Create(String projectDirectory, String gitRepoDirectory, ICloudBuild cloudBuild, Nullable`1 overrideBuildNumberOffset, String projectPathRelativeToGitRepoRoot)
   at Nerdbank.GitVersioning.Tasks.GetBuildVersion.ExecuteInner()
   at MSBuildExtensionTask.ContextAwareTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
```

Comment: Is any input to resolve this issue?